# A composition of a simple extension and a separable extension is simple

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, fields, field-extensions

Let $K/L/M$ be a tower of finite field extensions with $K/L$ separable and $L/M$ simple (in the sense of being generated by a single element). How does one show that $K/M$ is also simple?

I know that this is standard material, but I am trying to understand the argument in the context of residue fields of smooth curves over a field.

Here is what I know. One should probably use Artin's primitive element theorem and so the point is to prove that $K/M$ has only finitely many field subextensions $K'/M$. One may replace $M$ by $K' \cap L$ to reduce to looking for only those subextensions that are disjoint from $L$. How does one see that there are only finitely many such $K'$? (I think I know how to conclude by using flat descent for étale algebras, but it would be ridiculous to argue like this: what is the *correct* argument?)

Comment: I would strongly encourage removing the argumentation in the second paragraph.  I think that "I know that this is standard material, but I am trying to understand the argument in the context of residue fields of …" is much less confrontational and says the same, and anyone who's not swayed by it also won't be swayed by the longer current second paragraph.

Comment: The claim would follow from the following form of the primitive element theorem: If $L=K(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ with $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$ separable algebraic over $K$ and $a_n$ algebraic over $K$, then $L=K(a)$ for some $a$. Would that answer your question?

Comment: In the form [suggested](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371269/a-composition-of-a-simple-extension-and-a-separable-extension-is-simple#comment938757_371269) by @ArnoFehm (Theorem 5.1 of [Fields and Galois theory (4.61)](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf)), Milne gives an elegant proof (probably the standard one, but I don't have any other reference to hand to check):  the finitude of intermediate fields is obvious if the ground field is finite; otherwise, a generic linear combination of the $a_i$'s is a primitive element.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.